# MS Access Query using IFF to compare values

Tags: ms-access, if-statement, aggregate-functions

I am trying to build a query which will look  at the data in two fields in two different tables and check to see if the data is the same, if it is I want it to return the number of times it is matched, if it isn't I simply want it to return the text saying "No viewings".

I have constructed this query in my access database which has the field from the first table "Property" and the second field I want it to compare the data with, "Viewings". I have build the following expression using the build tool, however I am stuck to make it work since every time I get this error message when trying to run the query: "Your query does not include  the specified expression 'Property Viewed' as part of an aggregate function."

```
totalViewings: IIf([Viewings]![Property Viewed]=[Property]![ID],Count([Viewings]![Property Viewed]=[Property]![ID]),"No Viewings")
```

Any help how to overcome this error would be very appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest doing something like this:

1) Assuming this is something you are developing yourself, make sure your data structure is all in order first. Since I dislike relatively code-hostile identifiers, I'd have the tables as so -

*Properties* - `PropertyID` (AutoNumber, primary key), `HouseNumberOrName`, `Street`, etc.

*Viewings* - `ViewingID` (AutoNumber, primary key), `PropertyID` (Number/Long Integer), `ViewingDate`, etc.

In the Relationships view, `Properties.PropertyID` would then be set up to point to `Viewings.PropertyID` in a one-to-many relation.

2) Your actual query I would then break into two, the first to compile the data and the second to format it for display. The first would go like this, saved as `ViewingCounts`...

```
SELECT Properties.PropertyID, Count(Viewings.PropertyID) As ViewingCount
FROM Properties LEFT JOIN Viewings ON Properties.PropertyID = Viewings.PropertyID
GROUP BY Properties.PropertyID;
```

... and the second like this, saved as `ViewingCountsForDisplay`:

```
SELECT Properties.*, IIf(ViewingCount = 0, 'No viewings', ViewingCount) AS Viewings
FROM Properties INNER JOIN ViewingCounts ON Properties.PropertyID = ViewingCounts.PropertyID
ORDER BY Properties.PropertyID;
```

Comment: That's a nice solution, thanks. You made a slight error in the first query though- in the LEFT JOIN 'Propoerties.Proporty.ID' should equal to 'Viewings.ViewingID' I implemented it and it works great!